# Won't write to database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to write two objects called 'Friend' and 'Social' to the database. Friend writes no problem, but 'Activity' wont work.

DatabaseHandler code:

```
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FRIENDS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

    String CREATE_ACTIVITIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ACTIVITIES + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FRIEND + " TEXT," + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DAY + " TEXT" + KEY_MONTH + " TEXT" + KEY_YEAR + " TEXT"+ KEY_FRIEND_ID + " TEXT" +")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_ACTIVITIES_TABLE);


}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FRIENDS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ACTIVITIES);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addContact(Friend friend) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, friend.getFirstName());
    values.put(KEY_LASTNAME, friend.getLastName());
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, friend.getEmail());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_FRIENDS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Adding new social
void addSocial(Social social) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FRIEND_ID, social.getFriend_ID());
    values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, social.getDescription());
    values.put(KEY_FRIEND, social.getFriend());
    values.put(KEY_DAY, social.getDay());
    values.put(KEY_MONTH, social.getMonth());
    values.put(KEY_YEAR, social.getYear());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_ACTIVITIES, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}



// Getting All Contacts
public List<Friend> getAllContacts() {
    List<Friend> contactList = new ArrayList<Friend>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_FRIENDS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Friend friend = new Friend();
            friend.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            friend.setFirstName(cursor.getString(1));
            friend.setLastName(cursor.getString(2));
            friend.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
            // Adding contact to list

            contactList.add(friend);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}




// Getting All Activities
public List<Social> getAllActivities() {
    List<Social> activityList = new ArrayList<Social>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ACTIVITIES;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    Social social = new Social();
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            social.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            social.setFriend(cursor.getString(1));
            social.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));
            social.setDay(cursor.getString(3));
            social.setMonth(cursor.getString(4));
            social.setYear(cursor.getString(5));
            social.setFriend_ID(cursor.getString(6));


            // Adding contact to list

            activityList.add(social);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }


    return activityList;
}
```

This is in the activity which tries to add a new social object to the DB. It does not give me and errors but shows up blank when I try to display all social objects in the database.

```
            Social social = new Social();
            List<Friend> friends = db.getAllContacts();
            for(Friend friend: friends)
            {
                if(friend.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem())))
                {
                  social.setFriend(friend.getFirstName() + friend.getLastName());
                  social.setFriend_ID(String.valueOf(friend.getId()));
                  social.setDescription(rs3.getText().toString());
                  social.setDay(String.valueOf(simpleDatePicker.getDayOfMonth()));
                  social.setMonth(String.valueOf(simpleDatePicker.getMonth()));
                  social.setYear(String.valueOf(simpleDatePicker.getYear()));
                  found = true;

                }
            }

            if(found)
            {
                db.addActivity(social);
            }
```

Comment: The code that writes the data is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will not create the activities table as you would expect due to commas being omitted,

```
String CREATE_ACTIVITIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ACTIVITIES + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FRIEND + " TEXT," + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DAY + " TEXT" + KEY_MONTH + " TEXT" + KEY_YEAR + " TEXT"+ KEY_FRIEND_ID + " TEXT" +")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ACTIVITIES_TABLE);
```

*That is commas have been omitted after the column type (TEXT) for the KEY_DAY column, for the KEY_MONTH column and for the KEY_YEAR column.*

Rather it would create a table along the lines of *(noting that variables, such as KEY_ID would be replaced with the value of the respective variable, which could affect the outcome)* :-

columns:-

- KEY_ID (TYPE INTEGER and the PRIMARY KEY)
- KEY_FRIEND (TYPE as TEXT)
- KEY_DESCRIPTION   (TYPE as TEXT)
- KEY_DAY (TYPE as TEXT KEY_MONTH TEXT KEY_YEAR TEXTKEY_FRIEND_ID TEXT)

As such the insert would not insert a row as columns KEY_MONTH .... KEY_FRIEND_ID would not exist.

The corrected code could be :-

```
        String CREATE_ACTIVITIES_TABLE = 
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ACTIVITIES + 
            "(" + 
            KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + 
            KEY_FRIEND + " TEXT," +
            KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT," + 
            KEY_DAY + " TEXT," +    //<<<<<<<< added comma 
            KEY_MONTH + " TEXT," +  //<<<<<<<< added comma
            KEY_YEAR + " TEXT," +   //<<<<<<<< added comma 
            KEY_FRIEND_ID + " TEXT" +
            ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ACTIVITIES_TABLE);
```

After changing the code you would need to do **one** of the following (note data may be lost) :-

- delete the App's Data
- uninstall the App
- increment the Database version

When **one** of the above has been done you can then rerun the App.

*Note the above code has not been tested so it may have some errors.*

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is wrong in the create table SQL. Missing commas.